# React: Using .map won't display any data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, jsx

I use asp.net core and react for a project. Everyting is happening in Visual Studio. I make a call to the server to bring some appoinment(this is working, I checked with debuger and I have an element) but my problem is when I try to display the name of the item that was brought.

```
{this.state.appoinmentList.map(emp => emp.Name)} ,
```

here is the problem. The app opens but it won't show the name and with the debuger when I hover over 'emp' it shows:

> "emp is not defined"
>   and
>   "ReferenceError: emp is not defined

How can I fix the problem?Thank you.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScheduleComponent, Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month, Agenda, Inject } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-schedule';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Ajax } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { DataManager, ODataV4Adaptor, Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';
import { Data } from '@syncfusion/ej2-schedule/src/schedule/actions/data';

interface ScheduleDataState {
    appoinmentList: ScheduleData[],
    loading: boolean;
    value: string     
}

export default class Scheduler extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, ScheduleDataState>  {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { appoinmentList: [], loading: true, value: "yes" };
         fetch('api/Schedule/GetAll')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ScheduleData[]>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ appoinmentList: data, loading: false,value: "yes" });
          });  
    }

    render() {          
        return <p>
            {this.state.appoinmentList.map(emp => emp.Name)}
            { this.state.value }          
            </p>   

    }
}

export class ScheduleData {
    Id: number = 0;
    Name: string = "";
    SecondName: string = "";
    DateStart: string = "";
    DataStop: string = "";
    Notes: string = "";
    Status: string = "";

}
```

Comment: Just FWIW, you're missing a `t` after the first `n` in `appoinmentlist` (should be `appointmentlist`). But it seems to be consistent, so this is just a side note, it's not the problem.

Comment: Provided no errors occur and `data` isn't an empty array, I can't see any reason that wouldn't be showing the employee names. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (You'll have to use `setTimeout` to emulate ajax.)

Comment: There are a couple of other issues (neither of which I think is the problem you're asking about): 1. You're falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API, you should be checking for HTTP success (`response.ok`) before using the data (calling `json()`), see [this post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my anemic little blog for details. 2. You shouldn't start ajax within the constructor of a class component. The correct place to start an asynchronous process like that is [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Comment: [**Works for me**](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-pine-qemrv), if I make some reasonable assumptions.